# Limpiar un jPanel

Tags: java, jtextfield, jbutton, jpanel

espero estén bien, mi problema está en que tengo un jPanel que al buscar por id, me envía una imagen, el problema viene cuando quiero buscar otra imagen de la DB, pongo un id diferente y no la carga y se queda mostrando la anterior.
Este es el código que tengo para que el botón me muestre la imagen

````
            Connection con = objCon.getConexion();
            ps = con.prepareStatement("SELECT Foto FROM becados WHERE id=?");
            ps.setString(1, txtCodigo.getText());
            rs = ps.executeQuery();

            BufferedImage buffimg = null;
            byte[] image = null;
            while (rs.next()) {
                image = rs.getBytes("foto");
                InputStream img = rs.getBinaryStream(1); // reading image as InputStream
                try {
                    buffimg = ImageIO.read(img);
                    ImagenMySQL imagen = new ImagenMySQL(jpImagen.getHeight(), jpImagen.getWidth(), buffimg);
                    jpImagen.add(imagen);
                    jpImagen.repaint();

                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(Principal.class
                            .getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }

            Image img = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(image);
            ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(img);
            lblFoto.setIcon(icon);

            rs.close();
            
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.err.println(ex.toString());
        }```
Gracias por su atencion e intencion de ayudarme, se los agradezco
````

Answer (score 0):

La solucion es que debes actualizar tu interfaz UI para eso usa el metodo jpImagen.updateUI() debería funcionar adecuadamente después de agregarlo.

```
        BufferedImage buffimg = null;
        byte[] image = null;
        while (rs.next()) {
            image = rs.getBytes("foto");
            InputStream img = rs.getBinaryStream(1); // reading image as InputStream
            try {
                buffimg = ImageIO.read(img);
                ImagenMySQL imagen = new ImagenMySQL(jpImagen.getHeight(), jpImagen.getWidth(), buffimg);
                jpImagen.add(imagen);
                jpImagen.repaint();
                jpImagen.updateUI()

            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Principal.class
                        .getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }

        Image img = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(image);
        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(img);
        lblFoto.setIcon(icon);

        rs.close();
        
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.err.println(ex.toString());
    }
```

Comment: Hola bro, no sirve así, ya lo agregue y no aparece, se queda con la misma imagen que tenia...